# Add Interceptors for MockMvcBuilders webAppContextSetup

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, mockmvc

I am writing unit test for controller.

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = MyControllerWebConfig.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration
    public class MyControllerTest{
       @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
        ....
        @Test  
        public void testSomeThing()
        {
         // wanna do something like below:
         mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                   .addFilter(new someFilter())
                   .addInterceptors(new MyInterceptor())
                   .build();
          ....
        }
    }
```

I know that addInterceptors works only with statndaloneSetup(). How can we make it work with webAppContextSetup()

Comment: In a web app context, your interceptors would be beans registered in the context itself.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis , sorry, I did not get you. I want MyInterceptor() to be called here. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. If you're testing your configuration from a web application context, the interceptor should have been registered as a `@Bean` there.